# How to configure SMS URL of Twilio number?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-functions

I am getting an (Error: 30008) Unknown error inside the Twilio message logs.

[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfpLc.png)

To fix this issue we would have to configure SMS URL of Twilio number.

So, Can anybody help me how to configure SMS URL of Twilio number step by step?

Any valuable suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Have a look at [detailed documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages)

Comment: after proper configuration still error persist then do post your code here!

Answer (score 4):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

To configure the SMS URL for your number you need to go to your console, to your [Twilio numbers](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/incoming), edit your numbers by clicking on them and then entering a URL (or choosing a Twilio Function or TwiML Bin) in the Messaging section.

[image]

Check out this tutorial on [receiving SMS messages with your Twilio number](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-receive-and-reply) to learn more.

Comment: Hi, dear @Philnash

Thanks for the guidance, I have one more question, I am getting 30008 UNDELIVERED error message on my Twilio Account, Can you please help me, how to fix this issue?

Comment: @Abhishek The best thing for you to do would be open a new question and provide as many details as you can. Hopefully I can help then.